# Returning results while a task is still running

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactor

I have a method that needs to return results immediately after it's called, even all the tasks in this method are not complete.

In this scenario:

1. User submits an address to deposit funds to
2. I want to save their addresses and send them a deposit address
3. I want to start a task to start checking if the user deposited their funds to the deposit address

Step 2 is what I am returning and step 3 is what I want to keep running in the background after I return to step 3.

I am not sure what direction to take to orchestrate these events. Below is my method, not sure exactly what to do about the         `addressRegistrationService.watchAndTransact(userAddresses);`
task. It could take up to a full day to complete and the user needs the deposit address returned before it can deposit the funds.

```java
@PostMapping("/registeraddress")
public ResponseEntity<Mono<UserAddressesDTO>> addUserAddress(@RequestBody UserAddresses userAddresses) throws Exception {
    log.info("Registering {} with addresses {}", userAddresses.getAccountId(), userAddresses.getAddresses());

    //Checking if we can use the user provided addresses and account id
    if (addressRegistrationService.isRegistrationValid(userAddresses)) {
        throw new InvalidAddressException("Address is invalid");
    }

    log.info("Deposit Address is {}", generateJobcoinAddress.generateJobcoinAddress());

    //Generate the deposit address and add it the UserAddress
    String depositAddress = generateJobcoinAddress.generateJobcoinAddress();

    //Add input and deposit address to the object
    UserAddressesDTO userAddressesDTO = new UserAddressesDTO(userAddresses.getAccountId(), depositAddress, userAddresses.getAddresses());

    //Request the Jobcoin Service to start watching for the transaction
    //Once Jobcoin Service detects it will post the transaction to the house account
    //then to the user addresses - > we will be notified separately once this is complete
    addressRegistrationService.watchAndTransact(userAddresses);

    //Store addresses in database, calls the data-service to store these details
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(addressRegistrationService.saveAddressDB(userAddressesDTO));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CompletableFuture`. So your code will look like...

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> addressRegistrationService.watchAndTransact(userAddresses));
```

It will run your `watchAndTransact` method in a different thread. And main thread will not wait for result. So basically it will run on background.

Note: But incase of failure you will not know whats happened. So you can add some custom metrics & logs. This can be part of service it-self.

```java
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    try {
        addressRegistrationService.watchAndTransact(userAddresses);
        // Notify user
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // custom metrics implementation here
        // log error here
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that by default `runAsync` uses Fork-Join pool which has limited thread count and not intended for IO operations.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi what do you suggest then? Or how to configure `runAsync` so that I can use it for IO

Comment: Depends on what is going on inside watchAndTransact method. If that is a reactive method, then a `subscribe` might be enough. Otherwise runAsync has an overloaded version which accepts an Executor where you can pass a custom threadpool.